# can we validate date from XSD in MM-DD-YYYY format?

Tags: xml, xsd

can we specify MM-DD-YYYY format date restriction in XSD on element which we want to restrict ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible with an regex

```
<xsd:simpleType name="Date">
   <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
     <xsd:pattern value="\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}"/>
   </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Left is of course that the range should be checked also. Maybe you can extend the regex to only accept certain numbers.

Comment: with the above pattern 30-30-2010 is also valid right, is there any way that i can restrict valid date only ?

Comment: Maybe this could be done with a schematron http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schematron rule but I am not familiar with this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with a pattern restriction on a string.

On a machine-readable format I'd advise using the International standard (which is also your national standard ANSI X3.30) as it is expected, widely supported and well known.

If it's intended to be displayed to a human directly rather than processed by the consuming machine, the a local convetion is fine, though it's important to be clear that it's being used.